# Should I keep a 1:1 scale for a vehicle wrap vinyl print made in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, print-design, file-size

I'm busy with my first vehicle wrap design - and I don't know what size
to make my design in Photoshop CS6 - the width of the "[bakkie](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bakkie)" is 4436mm x 1300mm.

If I use that in Photoshop the file size is over a gigabyte. What dimensions should my artwork be?

Comment: While we can provide some generic rules-of-thumb, you really need to ask the vendor that will be printing this banner for you. They will tell you exactly how to set up your file.

Comment: It is perfectly reasonable for a full vehicle wrap done in Photoshop to be over 1GB.

Answer (score 4):

I deal with this question and situation every day. If we were printing it, I'd ask you to build the artwork at 100% size (4436mm x 1300mm) at 125 to 300 PPI (Pixels Per Inch).

Then I would suggest that you avoid using Photoshop for this job if at all possible, and instead provide vector artwork from something like Illustrator. As you've discovered, the files you want to make are gigantic as raster at that size and resolution.

However, since I don't think my company is the one printing your job, (just a guess!) I would suggest that you contact the actual print company and ask them for their **Prepress** or **File Prep Guidelines**.

Answer (score 1):

Simple design your file with 10% of scale and 720 ppi.
When you rip your file scale out to 1000%.
I do this every day, no issues.

Comment: Same here. We do 100%, 50%, 25%, and 10%, depending on what is needed, and adjust the resolution to compensate.